# Obligated to pay very late invoice?

Tags: united-states, contract-law

A law firm did a lot of work for my company.  He sent us a first invoice and we paid it.  Nine months later, he told us that he forgot to bill us for some of the work that he did for us and he sent us a second invoice.

Let's assume for the purposes of this question that he did all the work described in the two invoices and that the work was satisfactory.

We are annoyed to receive a second invoice nine months late.  We already closed the books for last year and it messes up our budgeting.

Do we have a legal basis for not paying or asking for a discount for the second invoice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless there is a term in your contract that time bars late invoices you have to pay providing it was ladled within the statute of limitations wherever you are. The shortest SoL I have ever encountered is 4 years so that is unlikely to help?

Comment: Thanks, I expected that to be the answer, but I was hoping I might have missed something...

Comment: It doesn't mean you can't try to negotiate a discount - if you don't ask, you don't get.

Comment: @Kekito Absolutely express your displeasure. If the law firm values your business relationship then one might expect them to want to appease you.